# How to import a .cpp C++ native library into Android Studio

Tags: java, android, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface

I have a .cpp file that is a native library (called "native-lib.cpp") I would like to import into a project in Android Studio so that I can access it by running

```
System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
```

I also have a CMakeLists.txt file that contains the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
enable_language(CXX)
add_library(native-lib SHARED
        native-lib.cpp)
```

How do I go about importing this library into Android Studio? Can I just copy the files into a certain directory, do I have to edit some project files, or what?

Comment: I hope it'll help you: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is in same project then you don't need to include in android studio. Android studio will automatically generate and add the library in your apk when you build it or run it in your device.